# Webpack + Babel is transpiling Webpack loaders, how do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I thought Webpack + Babel would only transpile application code, not code used for the Webpack build. However, it seems to be transpiling code from `css-loader`, `mini-css-extract-plugin`, etc, which is causing the following error:

```
ERROR in ./styles/main.scss
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function
```

If I add the following to `exclude`, this error is fixed:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(j|t)sx?$/,
        include: [APP_ROOT, path.resolve('./node_modules')],
        exclude: [
          path.resolve('./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin'),
          path.resolve('./node_modules/css-loader'),
        ],
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },
      ...
```

I thought I wouldn't need this because Babel shouldn't be transpiling packages used for Webpack's build process. I added `node_modules` to `include` because some packages use code that wouldn't work in older browsers.

Comment: Can you provide a repo which reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for that could be related to the include option on your rules, why dont you try to put the reference of node_modules in the resolve option, this way webpack looks through the declared entry and parses what it needs to resolve but excluding from transpiling the declared exclusions.

```
entry: SRC_DIR + '/main.js',
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [SRC_DIR, 'node_modules']
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['eslint-loader']
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I want to transpile application code in `node_modules`, this prevents it from being transpiled. Some packages use newer syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding all of `node_modules`, and only include the node_module resources you actually need to be transpiled. I'm betting this will make your problem go away.

Comment: Yeah this would work, but I have to figure out exactly which packages use new syntax, and AFAIK there's no tool that does this.

Answer (score 0):

For transpiling special files like, css or png or jpg or svg, etc from your project folders, certain loaders are required, but during transpiling it also picks up loader files so that format of your file (like css) can be matched and analysed for errors. This is then transpiled to give you the final build files.